# Prove that if binary words $x$ and $y$ have even weight, then so does $x+y$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I am stuck on an exercise from "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by Charles C. Pinter, and there are technically three parts to the question:

> Given that the *weight* of a binary word $x$ is the number of $1$s in the word and is denoted by $w(x)$, prove the following:
>
> a) If words $x$ and $y$ have even weight, so does $x+y$.
>
> b) If words $x$ and $y$ have odd weight, then $x+y$ has even weight.
>
> c) If word $x$ has odd and $y$ has even weight, then $x+y$ has odd weight.
>
> Note that both $x$ and $y$ must be of the same length.

My attempt of proving these statements was along the line of using the identity $w(x+y) = d(x,y)$ where $d(x,y)$ refers to the *distance* between the words $x$ and $y$. I then noticed that if both $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, suppose at the $i$-th digit we have $x_i \neq y_i$, then there exists another digit $j$ such that $x_j \neq y_j$. This shows that the resulting $x+y$ has even weight. However, I cannot prove this. I just needed a hint and not the whole solution to the given problems.

---

To clarify some of the terminologies used in this post:

1. If a word $x=x_1x_2...x_n$ and a word $y=y_1y_2...y_n$, then the resulting sum $x+y$ is $z=z_1z_2...z_n$, where

$$\
z_i = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } a_i = b_i \\
1 & \text{if } a_i \neq b_i
\end{cases}
\\$$

2. The distance $d(x,y)$ refers to the number of position in which the words $x$ and $y$ differ.

Comment: What is meant by $x+y$ here?

Comment: If a word $a = a_1a_2...a_n$ and a word $b = b_1b_2...b_n$, then the resulting sum $a+b$ is $e = e_1e_2...e_n$ where $e_i = 0$ if $a_i = b_i$ and $e_i = 1$ if $a_i \neq b_i$

Comment: What are the possible values of those $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n$ in words $a$ and $b$? Should I assume binary words, but not ternary words etc.?

Comment: Do you have b,c following from a without having to repeat similar steps? Something you can add to switch the weight from odd to even and get you back into the setup of part a.

Comment: Do all words have the same number of characters?

Comment: The words in question are in binary, and they must be of same length.

Comment: Maybe try induction on $n$. For each of parts a), b) and c), assume that the final bits $(x_n,y_n)$ are either $(0,0), (0,1)$ or $(1,1)$.

Comment: For the first one, note that $w(a+b)=w(a)+w(b)-2w(a*b)$ where $a*b$ denotes bit-wise and.

Comment: @MichaelBurr do you think my answer to this post is acceptable? Or do I have to make adjustments?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that w(a+b) = w(a) + w(b) - 2*w(a&b), where the operator '&' is the bitwise AND operator. Now, w(a) and w(b) are both even, so we can express them as 2x and 2y, respectively, where x and y are non-negative integers. That gives us w(a+b) = 2x + 2y - 2*w(a&b) or w(a+b) = 2(x+y-w(a&b)) that is always even. That proves (a).
You can do a similar approach for (b) and (c) knowing that the sum of 2 odd numbers is even, and the sum of an odd number and an even number is an odd number.

Comment: If I can prove $w(a+b)=w(a)+w(b)-2w(a&b)$, then everything else would fall into place. After giving much thought, I could not do it.

Comment: Think like this: a & b results in a word where all bits that are 1 exist both in a AND b, so you count 2 bits for each coincidental bit (1 from a and 1 from b). When you do a + b, all coincidental bits that are set to 1, result in 0 (1 + 1 = 0), so the result of w(a + b) is the number of bits in EITHER a or b. So, w(a+b) = bits set in a + bits set in b - 2 times coincidental bits in a and b. Does it help?

Comment: It does help, but I will look into a way of formalizing this result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd like to thank everyone for their constructive replies, which enabled me to write this answer.

We define set $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$ as the following:
$$S_1 := \{i \in \mathbb{N}\mid x_i \neq y_i \text{ for } i \leq n\}$$
$$S_2 := \{i \in \mathbb{N}\mid x_i \neq 0 \text{ for } i \leq n\}$$
$$S_3 := \{i \in \mathbb{N}\mid y_i \neq 0 \text{ for } i \leq n\}$$

where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the $i$-th digit of binary words $x$ and $y$ respectively, and $n$ is the length of the words. Since $w(x+y) = d(x,y)$, where $d(x,y)$ refers to the number of positions of which the words $x$ and $y$ differ, it follows that $|S_1|=d(x,y)=w(x+y)$, $|S_2|=d(x,0)=w(x)$, and $|S_3|=d(y,0)=w(y)$. Furthermore, if there exists $k$ such that $x_k = y_k = 1$, then $k \notin S_1$. Therefore,
$$|S_1| = |S_2| + |S_3| - 2|S_2 \ \cap \ S_3|$$
From this, we can deduce:
$$\text{ a) If $2 \ \mid w(x)$ and $2 \ \mid w(y)$, then $2 \ \mid w(x+y)$. }$$
$$\text{ b) If $2 \ \nmid w(x)$ and $2 \ \nmid w(y)$, then $2 \ \mid w(x+y)$. }$$
$$\text{ c) If $2 \ \nmid w(x)$ and $2 \ \mid w(y)$, then $2 \ \nmid w(x+y)$. }$$